# InstantiationException on Orientation Change when DialogFragment is on the top

Tags: android

I have a `DialogFragment` defined as **inner** class in my `Fragment` class. On Orientation Change even the following exception is poped up:

```
 Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment my.package.fragments.ImportFragment$FailedImportDialog: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
        at android.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:96)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1682)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:861)
        at my.package.activities.ImportActivity.onCreate(ImportActivity.java:8)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
        ... 12 more
        Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class my.package.fragments.ImportFragment$FailedImportDialog; no empty constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
```

But I do have public constructor:

```
class FailedImportDialog extends DialogFragment {

        private EditText edtPassword;
        private Button button;

        public FailedImportDialog() { // Here it is!
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.another_password_dialog, container, false);
            edtPassword = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.another_password_dialog_et_password);

            getDialog().setTitle(R.string.failed_to_decrypt);

            Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.another_password_dialog_btn_ok);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

            });

            return v;

    }
}
```

Here is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/another_password_dialog_tv_text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/what_password_did_you_use">
    </TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/another_password_dialog_et_password"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:inputType="textPassword">
        <requestFocus>
        </requestFocus>
    </EditText>

    <Button android:id="@+id/another_password_dialog_btn_ok"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="OK">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Do you guys know why this exception happens? Thank you!

**UPDATE:** If I move a class to a separate file there is no such an exception, everything goes smoothly. So the question is - why this exception happens when `DialogFragment` is an inner class?

Comment: Can you post the Fragment's XML.  Also, can you show the code that instantiates the Fragment?

Comment: try making your class public like 'public class FailedImportDialog extends DialogFragment'

Comment: What is code at Line No: 8 in your ImportActivity.java file?

Comment: @Chintan, this is the Activity which holds Fragment on top of which DialogFragment is shown.

Comment: Hey Friend, I asked about CODE.

Comment: Oh, sorry... the code is just: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.import_activity);
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try making the inner class static:

```
public static class FailedImportDialog extends DialogFragment
```

I will post more explanation about this in a while. In the meantime, try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: No, I can't make it static because I made it inner in order to get access to outer class's members.

Comment: I can't, but it looks like I need to rethink the way I handle the situation. thanks.

Comment: @siik: ya unfortunately, the inner DialogFragment class needs to be static. I will write up a description shortly. i have to catch up with few important things for now.

Answer (score 7):

Calling setRetainInstance(true) will cause the FragmentManager to save your actual Fragment instance. Instead of destroying and recreating the Fragment, it will just pass the same one along to the new Activity.

Comment: This one works for me. Although the dialog will be automatically closed on orientation change, but at least it avoids InstantiationException.

Answer (score 0):

Define your inner class like this:

```
public class FailedImportDialog extends DialogFragment {
....
}
```

With the public notation.

Because, this is what your LogCat says:

```
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment
my.package.fragments.ImportFragment$FailedImportDialog: make sure class name exists 
is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but this didn't help, I'm still getting the same exception.